# How to select an entry without specific entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have two SQL-tables like this:

T1

```
Animal   Name
Cat      Paul
Cat      Miau
Cat      Paul
Cat      Peter
```

T2

```
Legs   Name
4      Paul
4      Miau
3      Paul
4      Peter
```

What I want to have is a table like this:

```
Animal   Legs   Name
Cat       4     Miau
Cat       4     Peter
```

I want to have all animals with a specific number of legs but not when we have two cats with the same name.

I tried doing something like these:

```
select  a.animal, b.legs, a.name
from animallistA as a join animallistB as b
on a.name = b.name 
where b.legs = 4 and not b.legs = 3
group by a.animal, b.legs, a.name
```

If I say `where b.legs = 4` then I'll also receive 'Paul' but If I say `where b.legs = 4 and not b.legs = 3` I receive nothing at all.

Is there a way not to receive the cats who have the same name and 4 legs but not the one that have the same name but either 4 or less(or  more) legs.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Formatting tip: skip the `<br>` tags etc. Instead while editing, mark the code and click `{}`.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if they  both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS far as I understood your question I suggest following query:

```
SELECT A.ANIMAL, A.NAME, B.LEGS 
FROM ANIMALLISTA A
INNER JOIN ANIMALLISTB B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS RC FROM ANIMALLISTB GROUP BY NAME) C ON A.NAME = C.NAME
WHERE B.LEGS=4
 AND C.RC=1
```

Output:

```
ANIMAL  NAME    LEGS
Cat Miau    4
Cat Peter   4
```

Comment: what is the need of left join if you give condition on the result of that in where clause

Comment: It's easier if someone has still to work on the query.  I don't think it change something.  Anyway, yes, in final version, one can write INNER JOIN instead LEFT JOIN in the fourth line of my query.

Comment: And that's is what you want (as in your question)

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` may do the job.

```
SELECT t1.animal, t2.legs, t2.name
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.legs = 4 AND 
      NOT EXISTS 
      (
          SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.legs != 4
      )
```

Comment: HI, I tried this one, But I'm also receiving cat + 4 + paul . And I do'nt want to receive him. But thanks. I'll triy to variate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can first take all the unique names of 4 legs animals ( from subquery ) and then join with the main table to get required result.

```
    select  a.animal, b.legs, a.name from animallistA as a join 
    (select name,max(legs) legs from animallistB  group by name having count(distinct legs)=1) as b
     on a.name = b.name and b.legs=4
```

From subquery we can get result

```
Legs   Name
4      Miau
4      Peter
```

Because distinct values in having condition fail for `Paul`. Joining this with main table gives the requested result

Comment: Can you post your output pls?

Comment: @etsa plz check my answer (I have changed having condition with distinct )

Comment: Yes now it works (but it's seem to me that more important than DISTINCT was moving WHERE LEGS=4 condition  and transforming it in AND B.LEGS=4 
 :-)

Answer (score 0):

> You might wanna try something like this, worked for me on My SQL 8.0.2
>   || cat_1 = T1 and cat_2 = T2

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT distinct * 
FROM cat_1 
INNER JOIN cat_2 ON cat_1.names=cat_2.name
),

SCTE AS
(
SELECT CTE.animal, 
CTE.legs, 
CTE.names, 
COUNT(CTE.names) over(PARTITION BY CTE.names) as Count
from CTE
)

SELECT 
SCTE.animal, 
SCTE.legs, 
SCTE.names
FROM SCTE
WHERE legs = 4
AND Count = 1;
```

Output:

```
animal   legs   names
Cat       4     Miau
Cat       4     Peter
```